# Does die() end your session in PHP?

Tags: php

If I execute:

```
die();
```

Will it also effectively call

```
session_write_close();
```

Because die stops the entire process?

Comment: Yes it will, the same way any script termination will. Object destructors will also run; though I'm not certain about any auto_append_file

Comment: no session will not be end. die(); only stops execution of the script.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No. As you can see on the PHP page: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php (because *die* is equivalent to *exit*)

> Shutdown functions and object destructors will always be executed
>   even if exit is called.

BUT, session_write_close is NOT a shutdown function. It will not run if you "die". I suggest you look into **session_register_shutdown**. This will register session_write_close() as a shutdown function and in this case, it will run on "die".

More Info: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-register-shutdown.php

Answer (score 7):

[`die`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.die.php) and [`exit`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) are equivalent. From the docs:

> Terminates execution of the script. Shutdown functions and object destructors will always be executed even if exit is called.

So php will still go clean-up routine. Anyway, if you want to do something custom on script shutdown you can register shutdown function using [`register_shutdown_function`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php).

```
function shutdown()
{
    //Some custom clean-up, logging and so on
}

register_shutdown_function('shutdown');
```

**Note:** if you register your custom shutdown function it will also be called when *fatal error* occurs.