# What does session_register_shutdown actually do?

Tags: php

From official php manual:

> `session_register_shutdown` — Session shutdown function
>
> Registers `session_write_close()` as a shutdown function.

So, what does session shutdown mean? What's the difference between `session_write_close` and this?

To make it clear, what does this function actually do? When shall we use it?

It seems few people are using and talking about this function on the web.

Comment: Did you read the rest of the page? "Registers session_write_close() as a shutdown function." The user comment giving an  equivalent for old PHP versions also makes pretty clear what it does.

Comment: Of course I read, but I still don't understand. "Registers session_write_close() as a shutdown function." When and why we may use this function?

Comment: You might not realize it yet, but you've answered your own question. Checkout the official documentation http://php.net/function.session-write-close.php.

Comment: +1 @Sven Sorry but in most cases the PHP docs explain the purpose, and provide examples, in this case however, there are no examples and no explanation as to why it should be used, it was worth asking, and helped me understand when I saw the accepted answer below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This function is rarely used actually, there is almost no discussion on the internet, I finally found the answer from the source code comments:

```
/* This function is registered itself as a shutdown function by
 * session_set_save_handler($obj). The reason we now register another
 * shutdown function is in case the user registered their own shutdown
 * function after calling session_set_save_handler(), which expects
 * the session still to be available.
```

From： https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/session/session.c

And, obviously, compared to the official manual, this clearly states what it exactly do.

This question is just looks silly.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot!  This should be in the online docs!

Answer (score 6):

This is a fair question. I was also confused by the documentation.

What I was able to extract after reading it a dozen times is that the function is just a shortcut version of the code

`register_shutdown_function('session_write_close');`

If you call die() or exit in a php script the session will not be properly closed (especially if you have a custom session handler). This function is nothing more than a shortcut.

My bootstrap code for my specific session handler looks like:

```
// Set the session handlers to the custom functions.
$handler = new SQLSrvSessionHandler();
session_set_save_handler(
  array($handler, 'sessionOpen'),
  array($handler, 'sessionClose'),
  array($handler, 'sessionRead'),
  array($handler, 'sessionWrite'),
  array($handler, 'sessionDestroy'),
  array($handler, 'sessionGC')
);
session_register_shutdown();
```

The function `session_register_shutdown` insures my function `SQLSrvSessionHandler::sessionClose` and `SQLSrvSessionHandler::sessionWrite` are called even if I run a die or exit statements.

I also found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14870057/does-die-end-your-session-in-php) helpful.

Answer (score 1):

> Rarely used

**The session shutdown function is called when the session is destroyed, giving you the opportunity to perform a final action with the session before it isn't available anymore (e.g. you could extract parameters from the $_SESSION variable).**