# What is the purpose of using session_register_shutdown()?

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I just want to find out when and why we should use session_register_shutdown().
please don't copy descriptions from php.net. 
Thanks

Comment: Maybe this will give you some idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14870057/does-die-end-your-session-in-php

Comment: Thanks for your answer , but I've got two questions : 
1 -How could we use this function?
2- What will happen if we use this function ?
RSVP

Comment: How about this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29810954/what-does-session-register-shutdown-actually-do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A shutdown function is the equivalent of a [destructor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Destructor_%28computer_programming%29) for code that is not object-oriented.

You can register a shutdown function if you want something to be executed if a certain component is no longer needed and you want to take an action, e.g. some sort of clean-up.

The session shutdown function is called when the session is destroyed, giving you the opportunity to perform a final action with the session before it isn't available anymore (e.g. you could extract parameters from the `$_SESSION` variable).

Usually, you will not need to use this function.

Answer (score 2):

That's a very good question and I had a hard time finding the right answer on internet. Anyway [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29811649/2588746) gave me a good hint.

There are two points to consider:

1. Custom shutdown functions registered with `register_shutdown_function` are *called in the same order as they were registered* (cf. [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php)).
2. `session_set_save_handler` registers `session_register_shutdown` as a shutdown function, which in turn registers `session_write_close` as a shutdown function.

The 2nd point is very important as it ensures that `session_write_close` **will always be called last**, so that other custom shutdown functions can access session data.

### Example:

Consider a case where we register two shutdown functions and one custom session handler:

```php
register_shutdown_function(func1);// registers `func1`
session_set_save_handler(...);// registers `session_register_shutdown`
register_shutdown_function(func2);// registers `func2`
```

In this example, the following functions will be called at shutdown:

```
func1();
session_register_shutdown();// registers `session_write_close`
func2();
session_write_close();
```

So no matter in which order the shutdown functions and custom session handlers are registered, `session_write_close` is always called last, so that `func1` and `func2` can access session data.

That's a smart trick from the PHP developers :)

The only case where we would need to call ourselves this function would be if we had a shutdown function which itself registered another function which required to access session data... quite unlikely I guess.

### UPDATE

I missed an important information from the [session_set_save_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) docs:

> When using objects as session save handlers, it is important to register the shutdown function with PHP to avoid unexpected side-effects from the way PHP internally destroys objects on shutdown and may prevent the write and close from being called. Typically you should register 'session_write_close' using the register_shutdown_function() function
>
> As of PHP 5.4.0 you can use session_register_shutdown() or simply use the 'register shutdown' flag when invoking session_set_save_handler()

So it looks like what I've been writing above is valid when the session handler is a class implementing `SessionHandlerInterface`. Otherwise one needs to manually call `session_register_shutdown()` from within the class constructor.

Comment: "it is important to register the shutdown function with PHP to avoid unexpected side-effects"  Thank you for digging this up.  This is exactly my problem.