# session becomes empty when accessed in another function

Tags: php, session, laravel-5, dropzone.js

I am using laravel framework 5.2. I am using dropzone for multiple images. The all images are successfully stored in session. Now problem is that when i accessed that particular session in another function it gives me blank result here is my balde file and function

```
enter code here
<---Dropzone-->
<div class="modal-body">
             <div class="dropzone-img">
                 <form id="my-awesome-dropzone" action="{{ url('/add-images')}}" class="fallback dropzone">
                             {{ csrf_field() }}

           </div>
        </div>
```

Now my controller having two functions

```
enter code here
public function add_images(Request $request){
    if($request->ajax()){
        $image=$_FILES['file'];
        if(!empty($image)){
            if($image['error']==0){
                $imgName = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name']);
                $ext = $imgName['extension'];
                $rand=mt_rand(5,1000000000).'.'.$ext;
                $destination=realpath('../public/images/ListingImages').'/';
                if(move_uploaded_file($image['tmp_name'], $destination.$rand)){
                    $request->session()->put('businessimages.'.$imgName['filename'].'.image',$rand);
                    $images = $request->session()->get('businessimages');
                    echo "<pre>"; print_r($images); die;  
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Now when i accessed the businessimages session in another function it gives me empty result.

 public function business_for_sale(Request $request){
     $images = $request->session()->get('businessimages');
     echo "<pre>"; print_r($images); die;
 }
```

Can anyone help me. Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is for you call the die() function when you set the session

```
$request->session()->put('businessimages.'.$imgName['filename'].'.image',$rand);
$images = $request->session()->get('businessimages');
echo "<pre>"; print_r($images); die;
```

You could see it
[Does die() end your session in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14870057/does-die-end-your-session-in-php)

So you could try to change it like

```
$request->session()->put('businessimages',$rand);
$images = $request->session()->get('businessimages');
echo "<pre>"; print_r($images); 
session_register_shutdown();
die;
```

Comment: thank you Xposl works like charm :) you have also one mistake you remove die in your answer

Comment: It is because you the key is different here. You should set it use key name businessimages `$request->session()->put('businessimages',$rand);` and get use the same key name `$request->session()->get('businessimages')`;