# PHP $_SESSION always loses the values, what's wrong?

Tags: php, session

I use Angular 6 for front-end with the following PHP code(snippet) as back-end:

```
session_start();

switch ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]) {
  case "GET":
    ...
    break;
  case "POST":
    if (isMatch("/user/login")) {
      if () {
        // if un & pw is ok
        ... // get the permission from db..., then
        $_SESSION['sid'] = session_id();
        $_SESSION['userName'] = $userName;
        $_SESSION['permissions'] = $permissions;
        sendResponse($response);
      } else {
        // if not
        sendResponse($response);
      }
    }
    if (isMatch("/file/upload")) {
      if (isset($_SESSION['sid'])) {
        // upload...
        sendResponse($response);
      } else {
        // no permission
        sendResponse($response);
      }
    }
    ...
    break;
}
```

End-point on front-end side:

```
  postLogIn(user: LoggingInUser): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(`${environment.baseServerHref}/${ENDPOINTS.LOG_IN}`, user);
  }

  postFiles(formData: FormData): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.request(
      new HttpRequest('POST', `${environment.baseServerHref}/${ENDPOINTS.UPLOAD_FILE}`, formData, {reportProgress: true})
    );
  }
```

Unfortunately the $_SESSION loses the values, so when I try to upload file with another request after authenticating(success), $_SESSION is empty.

How can I reach that I want?

**UPDATE:**

It is very easy example:

```
session_start();
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER["HTTP_ORIGIN"]}");

if (!isset($_SESSION['count'])) {
  $_SESSION['count'] = 0;
} else {
  $_SESSION['count']++;
}

echo json_encode(array('sid' => session_id(), 'count' => $_SESSION['count']));
```

Responses (I sent the request three times):

```
{"sid":"nttlcglqhpufuuu1a8vvv43uo9","count":0}
{"sid":"i4lip1deia00f9hb51u20dv7rn","count":0}
{"sid":"p5gdh7315a9gvgsbsm2kt4lvts","count":0}
```

Comment: Is this correct `$_SESSION['userName'] = $userName;      $_SESSION['permissions'] = $permissions;`? I.e. do those variables have values (they're not in your code)

Comment: Can you show what `sendResponse` is doing? Does it terminate the process using `exit`/`die`? In this case, `session_write_close` may not be called. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14870204/7362396

Comment: Also, Did you verify that the SESSION cookie is persisted / included in your next request in your frontend code?

Comment: I updated the issue above.

Comment: What I meant is open your browsers DevTools "network" monitor: Check the response headers of your requests: There should be a `Set-Cookie` header likely with a `PHPSESSID`. Is this included in your next requests request-header as `Cookie`?

Comment: check if [session.use-cookie](http://php.net/manual/ru/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-cookies) is set to "1" in php.ini

Comment: Set-Cookie is in the response, but it is not in the request headers in the next req.

Comment: I found the solution, check my answer below.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

I checked that the guys wrote in comments under my question.

Solution was...

**-on PHP side:**

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
```

**-on Angular side:**

```
return this.http.post(URL, user, {withCredentials: true});
```

withCredentials option should be set true.

Thanks guys:)